# DataStax Enterprise 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install error when using apt repository installation

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I used the apt repository installation approach exactly as outlined at docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html

There were no issues with the key. I have Oracle Server JDK 8 (latest as of today). Python 2.7 from Miniconda (also fresh install today), using defaults and allowing for prepending of PATH variables.

Following installation, there are errors regarding unmet dependencies:

```
dse-full : Depends: dse (=4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: dse-hive (=4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: dse-pig (=4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: dse-demos (=4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This server was completely nuked, so the Ubuntu environment was clean and updated.

I've deleted the sources.list.d folder, obtained a fresh key (deleting this folder also removed associations with any key pairs), and found the exact same error.

No idea here on how to correct and proceed.

Possibly pertinent additional info is the nuking was because in my previous attempt to install had the apt repository throw errors with both http and https, so downloaded file and installed after making it executable. No errors were thrown. However, when attempting to install the newest OpsCenter, was given errors pertaining to missing files and folders. I could not even uninstall per DSE documentation, as the /usr/share/dse folder was never created.

MORE INFORMATION RE: ERRORS AND ENVIRONMENT

Environment--

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)

$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

Cache Contents--

```
$ apt-cache madison dse-full | grep 4.8
  dse-full |    4.8.4-1 | https://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.3-1 | https://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.2-1 | https://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.1-1 | https://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.0-1 | https://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
```

REMOVAL--

```
$ sudo apt-get purge "dse*" datastax-agent

Package 'datastax-agent' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-demos' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-full' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-hive' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libcassandra' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libhadoop-native' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libhadoop' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libhive' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-liblog4j' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libmahout' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libpig' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libsolr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libspark' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libsqoop' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-libtomcat' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse-pig' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dse' is not installed, so not removed
```

NEW INSTALL--

```
$ sudo apt-get install dse-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dse-full : Depends: dse (= 4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: dse-hive (= 4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: dse-pig (= 4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: dse-demos (= 4.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went down this path myself.  I highly recommend the following:

1) Start over with an Ubuntu 12 node.  (For me, I used Amazon EC2 ami-15cbe87f.)

2) Once the node launches, download and run the latest Datastax Enterprise installer.  This upgrades the cluster, and puts hadoop home at /usr/share/dse/resources/hadoop.  (For me, I used DataStaxEnterprise-4.8.4.2016011118-linux-x64-installer.run)

2) In /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml:
   - set cluster name
   - use the internal up address 172.xx.xx.xx for seed node, listen_address, broadcast_address, broadcast_rpc_address
   - use 0.0.0.0 for rpc_address
   - use PropertyFileSnitch and edit /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-topology.properties.  Add entries for both the internal and external IPs.
      -- # Cassandra Node IP=Data Center:Rack
      -- 52.xx.xx.xx=us-east:1a
      -- 172.xx.xx.xx=us-east:1a
      -- # default for unknown nodes
      -- default=us-east:1a

3) Copy /etc/dse/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg to /etc/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg.  There is still a piece of code that is not using HADOOP_CONF_DIR.

4) Change Dir into /usr/share/dse/resources/hadoop/native/Linux-amd64-64/bin and chmod 4750 task-controller

5) Yes, 4750.

6) Don't forget to edit /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml to contain:
   - stomp_interface: 172.xx.xx.xx
   - local_interface: 172.xx.xx.xx
   - use_ssl: 0

7) At some point, you will need to go back and set up ssl.

8) sudo service dse start and check for errors in /var/log/cassandra/output.log and system.log

9) After a fix, you can delete your cluster and start over by going into /var/lib/cassandra and deleting everything there.  (Be careful!)  Then, go back to step 8.  Repeat until no errors.

10) Use this approach to get a Cassandra-only node working cleanly.  Then, use this approach to get a spark/hadoop node working cleanly.  Then, you can combine them and grow your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but some ideas to help troubleshoot this. One thing to note is the current version is 4.8.4 (not 4.8.6).

I just installed on a new Ubuntu 14.04 VM with just Java (OpenJDK) and Python installed and everything worked according to the documentation.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_72-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-internal-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b05, mixed mode)
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Some troubleshooting/cleanup steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ # confirm 4.8.4 is the latest package known
$ apt-cache madison dse-full | grep 4.8
  dse-full |    4.8.4-1 | http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.3-1 | http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.2-1 | http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.1-1 | http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages
  dse-full |    4.8.0-1 | http://debian.datastax.com/enterprise/ stable/main amd64 Packages

$ # remove any DSE packages
$ sudo apt-get purge "dse*" datastax-agent

$ # see if any packages marked as held
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
$ # for each package from above (package_name) set it to 'install'
$ echo "package_name install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

$ # try again to install DSE
$ sudo apt-get install dse-full
```

If these steps don't work, please include the full command and response from running apt-get install.

Comment: I think the issue is the version of Java.  I though I installed Oracle Server JDK 8, but it looks like it may have been the JRE?  The version running is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode).

Comment: Okay..this may not be the issue here:
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/java/latest/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java" 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/java/latest/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java   1         auto mode
* 1            /usr/java/latest/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java   1         manual mode

Comment: see added text regarding environment and error output to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be an issue with the DataStax package itself, but feels like there is a problem with the repo on the server.

In a lot of cases, the "unmet dependencies" is due to duplicate repositories. Remove any duplicates and perform a cleanup before installing again as @BrianC has documented above.

Comment: See my comment at bottom of next suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When you install try executing with the below version instead of dse-full. Previous to installing make sure to perform a "yum update"

sudo yum install dse-full-4.8.4-1

Per the below; Oracle JRE 8 meets requirements to install
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installRHELdse.html

If the installation fails can you post the install command and following output.

Comment: Look at your repositories next as suggested by flightc.

There should be only one repository listed in your repo file list. 

[datastax] 
name = DataStax Repo for DataStax Enterprise
baseurl=https://dsa_email_address:password@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installRHELdse.html

Comment: I tried installing from the tarball download you get from their webpage, and there were errors about sysaat being referenced, but not found, and an inability to install it.  Later in the log it stated datastax agent could not be installed due to dependence on sysaat.  About to try again after the server admin nuked the OS. This may have been the issue all along, because when I tried to uninstall it using datastax-agent, I got an error that the agent could not be found and no datastax files were installed to uninstall (see "REMOVAL" in post).

Comment: When you are testing installs stay with one path. Given the challenges you are having package installs might be better for you to work with. 

Did you look at your repository list? Do you have only one listed? Datastax has you create an account at their academy to get download credentials. Did you create those? Did you update yum afterwards?