# DataStax Enterprise 4.8.4, 2-node cluster on AWS EC2 formation snitch guidance

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I have just started working with DSE 4.8.4 in AWS EC2. Launched 2 "m3.xlarge" instances in us-west-1a availability zone. Of course, both nodes are in same region and same availability zone. This is fresh installation and does not have any user defined keyspace and no data etc.

On both instances, DSE 4.8.4 was installed as per datastax documentation. Service 'dse' starts on both nodes as individual with default endpoint_snitch as  "com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseSimpleSnitch" and I have used ALL private IP addresses on both nodes in cassandra.yaml file.

Now, when I changed 2nd node's .yaml file seeds property to point to 1st node Private IP address, dse service on 2nd node no longer starts with error indicating "Unable to find gossip ...", with hint to fix snitch settings.

I looked around and it seems, snitch should be used as Ec2Snitch.

Q1) Does both nodes need to have same snitch?
Q2) Will cassandra-rackdc.properties file need any changes due to us-west-1a?
Q3) Should I follow steps described in http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html ?

My objective is to build this 2-node cluster (manually as I did not use OpsCenter) with suitable changes to relevant config files.

I would really appreciate if someone could please point me in right direction?

Comment: 1) SimpleSnitch should work here though you shouldn't use it in production 2) can you paste the entire Error?

Comment: Similar question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015268/datastax-enterprise-4-8-4-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-install-error-when-using-apt-repos/35186222#35186222

Comment: Yes, that post helped and I had to do clear the data (sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*) as ran into issue of "Cannot start node if snitch's data center (DC1) differs from previous data center (Cassandra). Please fix the snitch configuration".

Comment: I have one follow-up question. In my that 2-node cluster setup, is it good idea to install OpsCenter on any one of the node and use GUI based interface to manage existing cluster? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to make it work using Ec2Snitch. Now, I created user defined keyspace & few tables. I used SimpleStrategy and RF=2, inserted data in one table from 1st node. Checked 2nd node and table exists But no data. Also, nodetool status is showing strange status on both nodes as UN & DN.  Owns column still show ?. I am not sure what's wrong or what did I miss?